# Finding the norm of a dual space (and then applying it to an element function)

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, duality-theorems

> Let $V=C([-1,1],\mathbb R)$ be the space of continuous functions from $[-1, 1]$ to $\mathbb R$ equipped with the norm $\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f(x)|$. Consider the mapping $L:V\to \mathbb R$ defined by 
>   $$L(f):=\int_{-1}^1\sin(\pi t)f(t)\mathrm d t\qquad\forall f\in V.$$
>   Show that $L\in V'$ and find its norm $\|L\|_{V'}$.

In the above, $V'$ refers to the dual space of $V$. I struggled with this question. Firstly, I wasn't sure how $\|\cdot\|_{V'}$ is defined. Is it the supremum norm of $V'$? Secondly, when I tried to visualize $\sup_{f\in V}|L(f)|$, I thought of $f$ as being a function with a steep gradient, with $f(0)=0$, $f(t)>0$ when $t>0$ and $f(t)<0$ when $t<0$ so that $\sin(\pi t)f(t)$ is positive. The steeper the gradient of $f$, the greater the area underneath $\sin(\pi t)f(t)$, without limit. So I could not find $\sup_{f\in V}|L(f)|$.

In a nutshell, how am I supposed to know how the norm $\|\cdot\|_{V'}$ is defined?

Edit: Why was I required to show that $L\in V'$? I ignored that because I thought it was obvious, but another question in the tutorial asked the same thing. How does one "show" that?

Comment: It's $$\lVert L\rVert_{V'} := \sup \bigl\{ \lvert L(f)\rvert : f \in V,\, \lVert f\rVert \leqslant 1\bigr\}.$$ Thus you consider only functions with $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant 1$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$.

Comment: Why did you choose $\|f\|\leq 1$?

Comment: It's the definition of the norm on the dual space. We can't take the supremum over all of $V$, since that would be $+\infty$ for all $L\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $V$ is a normed vector space, we associate to each $L \in V'$, the number $\left\| L \right\| = \sup\limits_{x\in V, \left\|x\right\| \le 1} L(x)$.

This number is called the norm of $L$ in $V'$, as it makes $V'$ a normed space.

P.S., one can check that $L\in V'$ by verifying the linearity of the addition and scalar multiplication.